# Interesting project for a child

Tags: 3d-design, cnc

A member of our hackspace wants to get their 8- and 11- year old kids<sup>1</sup> excited about 3D-printing and CNC cutting and makering in general. We have a weekly open training where people can design and print/CNC/laser an item of their choice like a dogboned box or a two-piece sword and hilt, or a name tag, or whatever. I need a few ideas prepared so we don't spend half our lesson on Thingiverse or in Fusion (more like a quarter)! I'm not a parent and my youngest friend is probably in their twenties.

What we have:

- a full bed 1200x1800 mm CNC (preferred, because it's loud and fast)
- Prusa mk3
- cheapo 80W 500x300 mm laser
- Fusion 360 based workflow, easy :)
- Arduinos and stuff

Ideas we've had: a minecraft creeper, done as a simple-ish box.

---

<sub>1: the (girls) are not interested in my normal kids' goto, which is: swords, shields. They are interested in: minecraft, dragons, horses. _o_/</sub>

edit: this is NOT an opinion-gathering post, though there may be more than one "correct" answer.  We need specific applications of 3d printing for a young audience. This collection of answers will be useful to evangelize making to a whole new generation!

Comment: Hot network question! :-)

Comment: Correction... *was* a HNQ, until it was closed... ah well... :-(

Comment: With some edits it could become a more solid question. It just needs to be more specific, and less open.

Comment: @StarWind0 - I quite agree. Shame really, as it got a lot of people's attention, and we need HNQs.

Comment: court3nay, can you reword it, so that it isn't *such* a shopping question? And not so opinion based (somehow)? I don't know if that is possible. Also, *maybe*, remove the "I know that this is an opinion based question" as that is the kiss of death, TBH.

Comment: @Greenonline How do we invite someone to a chatroom, we could help them that way and help rewrite it. Or do the edit ourselves.

Comment: @StarWind0 either super ping them from within the room or send them to this URL: [Public 3D Printing Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79830/public-3d-printing-room).

Comment: This question is in the idea nice, but it is also a can of worms in others: it is open ended, as the limits are very open, unless making it very general. There is no way there is a best answer for this, making it opinion based. And finally: the last sentence makes it an idea grab.

Comment: it's too late! you can ban it, but I got some great answers before you did :) Sometimes you have to let a question slide against the "rules" because it's in fact in direct synchrony with the *mission*, which is applications of 3d printing. It is in fact highly specific and there are in fact best answers. Just look!

Comment: Well, I'm glad that we managed to squeeze in some answers prior to the closure :-) I've just updated my answer, with some other links that I had in my note book.  Good luck inspiring the budding 3D Printing Engineers...

Comment: @court3nay the system did it based on user flags. Not an admin action. SO can be a tad strict given it's format unfortunately, and giving it got to hot question it was just a matter of time. The "this is opinion based" is probably what did it alone. Glad you got what you needed. Hope you post again soon.

Comment: Useful question. I asked something similar in Chat, and got no reply...

Comment: update: the girls made nameplates/name-tags with animals they had just drawn (inkscape) on the laser cutter.

Comment: @court3nay I know your passion or the question, but as it is, there simply is no way to serve this question justice at the stack, as each answer is equally valid.

Comment: @trish nope, this in fact specifically adheres to part 2 of https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask i.e. what to ask.

Comment: @court3nay there can't be a best answer, it is an open ended list question... or in other terms: a *shopping* question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is unfortunately, not a good fit for this site, as it stands, for as you say it is opinion based. However, it is great to see that you are getting kids into a relatively new technology (yes, I know it has been around for years, but it is still seen as new to *big media* and the general public).

<strike>My answer doesn't provide you with any actual designs, as you asked for.</strike> However, just to add an idea or two that I have been thinking about recently, in order to engage kids:

- Have you thought about using 3D printing pens (as side projects to the main feature of the printer)? Although I'm not so sure that the fumes at such close proximity would be that great, unless using PLA. That really would show close up the additive process.
- Also, there is a lot of useful sites to be found on [google](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=T3d%20printing%20for%20kids) (which you have probably seen), such as:

  - [kidscodecs - What is 3D printing?](https://www.kidscodecs.com/what-is-3d-printing/)
  - All3DP has [3D Printed Toys – 11 Ideas for Children of all Ages](https://all3dp.com/1/3d-printed-toys-kids-3d-printing-toys/), but these *seem* to need to be purchased.
- Alternative applications for kids, from [Best CAD Software for Kid Creators](https://3dprint.com/159445/best-cad-for-kids/), that might be worth considering if Fusion 360 doesn't float their <strike>Benchy</strike> boat:

  - [Solidworks Apps for Kids](http://appsforkids.solidworks.com/),
  - SketchUp
  - 123D Design
  - Tinkercad;
  - LeoCAD
  - Leopoly
  - BlocksCAD
  - 3D Slash
  - Some other ideas from [3dPrint.com - 3d design app for kids](https://3dprint.com/tag/3d-design-app-for-kids/)
- Maybe, as all kids seem to have iPhones, or what have you, these days, how about an App for kids upon which they can play with a design, and then print it later? Such an app would probably provide examples for them to get started with. One such app is the [Toy Maker by AstroPrint](https://toymaker.astroprint.com) - although that may require a commercial printer, I'm not sure. However, other such apps for smart phones probably are out there.

As for examples, there are [42 kids](https://www.thingiverse.com/tag:kids_toy) toys tagged on Thingiverse, such as:

- [Save the last Unicorn [Game]](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2238123)
- [Cartoon Weiner Dog](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2855568)
- [Lily Bobtail (Peter Rabbit Series)](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2124806)
- [Grand Hillar](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:368229)

[image: Grand Hillar]

Also to take from IronEagle's idea, some fidget spinners:

- [Fidget Spinner](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2313626)
- [Kid Sized Generic Spinner](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2285700)
- [10mm Nut Fidget Spinner](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2245460)

Comment: you say it "isn't a fit for this site", but here you are with a bunch of good designs AND anyone in future looking here for "kids" will get a bunch of answers that I'd say are all factual and definitive. Good stuff! :)

Answer (score 4):

As @fred_dot_u mentioned above, keychains are a simple, personalized item to make.  In terms of interesting projects, things that I found intriguing when I first encountered 3D printing were objects that could not be made by other means, such as those "geared bearings" ([Google: geared bearings 3d print](https://www.google.com/search?q=geared%20bearings%203d%20print&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ9vvpn5LcAhXkKX0KHcqfBLQQsAQITA&biw=1576&bih=820&dpr=1.13)).  Given the popularity of figet spinners a while back, they could be an interesting item.  
 A captive ball in a box, or three joined rings, can also be set up as a 3D print, and could have the same effect, while being easier for the kids to design.

EDIT:  Some links to versions of items along the above lines.  Thingiverse tends to slowly break links, though, so these might not last:

- [Geared Bearing](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:53451)
- [Captive Ball](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:621854)
- [Three Rings](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4345)
- [Triple Gear](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:79310)
- [Self-aligning Bushing Keychain](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2148303)

Comment: Why the downvote?  OP asked for ideas for objects to make, not software to make it with.  They already mentioned they have a good workflow based on Fusion 360.

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe because you suggested geared bearings and not dragons and horses? Although, obviously, I can't see what's wrong with girls printing gears, personally, it is something that should be encouraged. Maybe if you could provide some direct links to gears and spinners on Thingiverse, that might garner you some upvotes? Here's a +1 as encouragement :-)

Comment: thankyou, I didn't downvote you, but the kid would say: what's a gear /bearing? maybe kids like things that are more obvious, like: a fidget spinner or something with a gear *in* it?

Answer (score 3):

Our local library makerspace holds summer camp for a limited number of lucky attendees, ages from 12-15 and the curriculum has a segment which appears to match your objective.

In the case of the Launch Pad Camp, the campers will be using [OnShape](http://onshape.com/) to create a keychain/nametag with text of their choosing. It will be an unremarkable 3mm thick x 35-40 mm wide x 70-80 mm long "plank" with a depressed center (by 1.5mm) and raised text. The mentors of the camp expect to be able to teach these campers how to use the software to perform tasks by rote. I assisted the mentor in the process as she had no idea how to use OnShape. Neither did I, but that never slows me down.

Another aspect of her camp is that it will (or may) include using [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/)

[image: scratch screencap]

and does include using a Scratch based program called [Ozoblocky](https://ozoblockly.com/) to interface with [Ozobots](https://ozobot.com/).

[image: ozoblocky screencap]

I suggested to her that she could use [BlockSCAD](https://www.blockscad3d.com/) to create the 3D objects, as the interface is nearly identical, and in my opinion, very easy to use.

Not surprisingly, BlockSCAD has a series of tutorials available on the [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xs0a4hzd1Tk).

The [editor for BlockSCAD](https://www.blockscad3d.com/editor/) is browser based removing the requirement to install on every computer.

[image: blockscad editor image]